# FlexDashboard - ggplot width to fill cell width

Tags: r, ggplot2, flexdashboard

Is there a way to get ggplot to fill the width within a flexdashboard cell, without specifying the fig.width, so that it is responsive?

In the example below, I'd like the single chart in each cell to fill from left to right, so the one in the top row would be much wider and the two below a little wider.

[image]

````
---
title: "Test Flex Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---
  
```{r include=FALSE}
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

```

Raw Data
===================================== 
  
Row
-------------------------------------
  
### **Upper Row** 
  
```{r}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```

Row
---------------------------
  
### **Lower Row, Col 1** 
  
  
```{r}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```

### **Lower Row, Col 2** 

```{r}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```
````

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is not possible as the ggplots are included as png's with a fixed aspect ratio when you render the flexdashboard. If you want the plots to fill the image container and to be responsive I would suggest to make use of `plotly::ggplotly`.

Comment: Thanks @stefan, that makes sense and explains why I couldn't find a way of doing it.  It also fits with my experience that it resizes for plotly.  If you add your text to answer, I'll mark it as the chosen one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with inline CSS! I know you said without `fig.width` settings, but I gave `fig.width` a default of 20(for my screen resolution), to let it fill the top column,  but with the below inline CSS code...

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.fluid-row {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
```
````

This gives the fluid row a responsive effect. so here is my full screen of the rendered flexdashboard.

[image]

and then here is when I drag the window on my desktop to a smaller window

[image]

below is your code with my solution, please let me know if you have issues. Thank you

````
---
title: "Test Flex Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.fluid-row {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
```
  
```{r include=FALSE}
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

```

Raw Data
===================================== 
  
Row
-------------------------------------
  
### **Upper Row** 
  
```{r, fig.width=20}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```

Row
---------------------------
  
### **Lower Row, Col 1** 
  
  
```{r}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```

### **Lower Row, Col 2** 

```{r}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = row.names(mtcars), y = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("MT Cars")

```
````

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.  Seems to work great.  How did calculate the width of 20 and where does the font size apply?  I've tried changing it but it seems to have no impact.

Comment: The 20 was decided just by it looking good on my screen, your screen resolution might be different, the font-size is just to help the text respond when the window changes, unless flex dashboard already auto resizes and I missed that