# R FlexDashboard Panel Horizontal Size

Tags: r, flexdashboard, geom-point

I'm working on a flex dashboard app, and when using geom_point, the graph seems to narrow.

Is there any way to make it wider? Fit full screen?

Here is the code:

```
eigpm %>% clean_names() %>%
 mutate(days_since_move_in = as.integer(gsub(",", "", days_since_move_in))) %>%
 filter(!is.na(days_since_move_in)) %>%
 filter(days_since_move_in!="") %>%
 arrange(desc(days_since_move_in)) %>%
 head(30) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=days_since_move_in, y=reorder(resident, days_since_move_in), color=property_name)) +
 geom_point(size=4) +
 scale_x_continuous(labels=comma, breaks = seq(5000,12000,1000)) +
   theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y=element_line(linetype="dashed",color="grey")) +
 labs(x="Days since Move In", y="Tenant", legend="Property Name")
```

Here is an image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nH7D.png)

Comment: Related posts: [FlexDashboard - ggplot width to fill cell width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025813/flexdashboard-ggplot-width-to-fill-cell-width), [Automatically resize ggplot2 plots in flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868548/automatically-resize-ggplot2-plots-in-flexdashboard)